# How to set $ip and $host in gulp for cloud9.io

Tags: ip, gulp, host, cloud9-ide, browser-sync

I can't find instruction to setup gulp browsersync in cloud9.io.
I think that settings ip and host for browsersync is wrong. I tryed do this in my gulpfile.coffee:

```js
require('coffee-script/register')
gulp = require('gulp')
$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()
browserSync = require('browser-sync')

gulp.task 'sass', ->
    return gulp.src(['./sass/**/*.sass'])
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.sass({
            indentedSyntax: true,
            errLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        # .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 3 version'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))

gulp.task 'stylus', ->
  gulp.src('./stylus/**/*.styl')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.stylus())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))

gulp.task 'server', ->
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./",
            port: process.env.PORT,
            host: process.env.IP  
        },
        browser: "google chrome"
    })

gulp.task 'watch', ->
    gulp.watch(['./sass/**/*.sass'], ['sass'])
    gulp.watch(['./stylus/**/*.styl'], ['stylus'])

gulp.task 'default', ['server', 'sass', 'stylus', 'watch']
```

And when i run command 'gulp':

```bash
suenot@car:~/workspace $ gulp
[17:20:06] Requiring external module coffee-script/register
[17:20:10] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/gulpfile.coffee
[17:20:10] Starting 'server'...
[17:20:10] 'server' errored after 249 μs
[17:20:10] ReferenceError: $PORT is not defined
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gulpfile.coffee:29:19)
at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:929:3
```

What I do wrong? Please help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud9.io tryed to open `browser: "google chrome"`.
I removed this string and transfer port and host parameters from server object and gulp started success.

```
gulp.task 'server', ->
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: './'
    },
    port: process.env.PORT,
    host: process.env.IP
})
```